# java CLASSPATH not working on command-line

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, classpath, javac

System details:

```
Ubuntu 17.10
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
```

I can't get my java program to run. I don't know why it won't find the class. It compiles with the `-classpath` flag, but doesn't find the class when running.

```
$ ls -ltra
total 668
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bvpx bvpx 653275 Jan 19 14:45 javax.mail.jar
drwxr-xr-x 3 bvpx bvpx   4096 Jan 19 14:59 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 bvpx bvpx    960 Jan 19 15:07 Example.java
drwxr-xr-x 2 bvpx bvpx   4096 Jan 19 15:07 .
```

Compiling without `-classpath` does not work (I thought `-classpath` defaulted to `.`?)

```
$ javac Example.java 
Example.java:2: error: package javax.mail does not exist
```

Specifying the `-classpath` helps, the program now compiles and produces `Example.class`:

```
$ javac -classpath javax.mail.jar Example.java
$
```

Here's the source code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class Example {
    static final int PORT = 587;
    /* ... */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /* ... */
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Sending...");
            transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Email sent!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Running the program produces this error:

```
$ java -Xdiag -classpath javax.mail.jar Example 
Error: Could not find or load main class Example
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Running `java` without `-classpath` causes the JNI to not find `javax/mail` even though it's in the directory.

```
$ java -Xdiag Example 
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
```

Why can't java find the Example class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing some fundamental concepts here.

The classpath gives a list of directories and JAR files to search for needed classes.  When trying to load a class `foo.bar.MyClass` that is not part of the standard library, the default classloader will look for it in each classpath element in turn, in order, until it finds the class or runs out of elements.

Note well, however, that it searches by fully-qualified name.  For classpath entries that are directories, that means that it looks for `foo/bar/MyClass.class` relative to the directory.  For classpath entries that are JAR files, it looks for `foo/bar/MyClass.class` relative to the root of the JAR.  Classes that belong to the unnamed default package are a little special, or so it may seem, because their class files (e.g. `InDefaultPackage.class`) are expected to be located directly in the root of the designated JAR or directly in the specified directory.

> Compiling without `-classpath` does not work (I thought `-classpath`
>   defaulted to `.`?)
>
> ```
> $ javac Example.java 
> Example.java:2: error: package javax.mail does not exist
> ```

The classpath *does* default to `.`.  This is the name of a directory, so when searching it for classes in, say, the `javax.mail` package, it looks for a subdirectory `javax/mail`, and if that is found, it examines the class files within.  Note that it *does not* descend into JAR files it discovers in the directory tree.  It looks only in those JARs explicitly named in the classpath.

The error message is telling you that `javac` didn't find any classes at all from the `javax.mail` package.  You could have solved it either by specifying the JAR in the compilation classpath (as ultimately you did) or by unpacking the JAR in the current directory.

> Specifying the `-classpath` helps, the program now compiles and produces
>   Example.class:
>
> ```
> $ javac -classpath javax.mail.jar Example.java
> $
> ```

Note that the compiler will store the classfile in a directory structure corresponding to its package, just where the `java` command will look for it.

> Running the program produces this error:
>
> ```
> $ java -Xdiag -classpath javax.mail.jar Example 
> Error: Could not find or load main class Example
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
> ```

You clarified in your answer that you solved this problem by removing a `package` statement from `Example.java`.  That's ok, but it doesn't really explain the problem, which is that `java` expects you to give it the *fully-qualified* name of the class.  That includes the package name if the class is in a named package.  Thus, if `Example.java` contained this package statement:

```
package com.my;
```

then the class name you would need to specify to `java` would be `com.my.Example`.  You specified just `Example`, which designates a class named "Example" in the default package, and your solution to the class not found problem was to move your class into the default package.

Note also that it is conventional and helpful to lay out your Java source files, too, in a directory structure matching their package structure.  Thus, the source file for class `com.my.Example` would conventionally be located in `com/my/Example.java`.  The Java compiler will rely on this scheme to locate sources for classes that it does not find.

> Running `java` without `-classpath` causes the JNI to not find
>   javax/mail even though it's in the directory.
>
> ```
> $ java -Xdiag Example 
> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
> ```

No, `javax/mail/Address` **was not** in the directory.  It was in a JAR file in the directory.  That's not at all the same thing, and the difference is significant.

Answer (score 2):

I had to set `-classpath` to include the current directory. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) `classpath` is delimited by `:`. The correct classpath string was:

```
javax.mail.jar:.
```

Below is a working example.

```
$ javac -classpath javax.mail.jar:. Example.java  
$ java -classpath javax.mail.jar:. Example 
Sending...
Email sent!
```

Another thing to note was that there was originally a `package` definition at the top of Example.java. I had to remove it.

Comment: So the source code presented in the question, which does not include a `package` statement, in fact does not reproduce the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example` error?

Comment: The combination of having the `package` statement in the source code while having the correct `javax.mail.jar:.` classpath still produces the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example` error. That error was solved by adding `:.` as part of the classpath and removing the `package` statement (which I had done before writing this question).

Comment: That's not the point, @bvpx.  You seem to be saying that the source you presented in your question is not sufficient to reproduce some of the errors you asked about.  I completely believe that, but I want to confirm.  Furthermore, if that is indeed the case then you should update the question to present source that actually reproduces the problem.